# How to create object using object.create?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code in a separate file that is referenced with tags

```
function _TEST()
     {
      var val; 
      this.get = function(x)
           {
            return val;
           }

      this.prop = 'testing';

      this.set = function(x)
           {
            val = x
            return val;
           }

      this.exp = function(x)
          {
            function meth(x)
               {
                return 'I am a private '+x;
               }
           return meth(x);
          }
     }
```

Now in the head section of the main page I have

```
var tst = new _TEST();
window.onload = function()
   {
    tst.set('Hello')
    alert(tst.get());
    var tst2 = Object.create(_TEST.prototype);
        tst2.prop = "testing"; // the only property that shows up for tst2 below

    var str = '';

    for(var x in tst)
      {
       str += x+" : "+tst[x]+"\n";
      }
    str += "\n\ntst2:\n"
    for(var x in tst2)
      {
       str += x+" : "+tst2[x]+"\n";
      }
    alert(str)
   }
```

The output from the call to alert is:

```
get : function (x) {
return val;
 }
 prop : testing
 set : function (x) {
   val = x;
   return val;
}
exp : function (x) {

function meth(x) {
    return "I am a private " + x;
}

return meth(x);
}


tst2:
prop : testing
```

As I understand it Object.create is suppose to create an object instande that inherits from the prototype.
but tst2 has none of those. What am I doing wrong here? 
This is being tested in Firefox 12.0 on Mac OSX and I am not sure what version of javascript it uses. I am
Using O'Reillies Javascript: the Definitive Guide (rhino book) to increase my knowledge of objects and related
code

Edit:
I figured it out:

it works with

```
var tst2 = Object.create(tst);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has not added any properties to the `_TEST.prototype`. The `_TEST` function adds properties directly to each instance created when a `new _TEST()` call is made. That has nothing to do with the prototype.